# Allow access to Linux server from Android phone (not on WiFi)

Tags: linux, android

There are cases when I need to access my Raspberry (Linux server) from my Android phone. Serves deny all connections except from my home network. 
Can I create a rule where my phone would also be allowed? 
It isn't a problem if the phone is connected to my home WiFi network. Problem is when I'm out of town and use only cellular phone signal. At first, I though about MAC address, but AFAIK in that cases, MAC address isn't available (only for IEEE 802 connections). The phone also doesn't have static IP address when traveling/reseting...
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The usual method is to set up a VPN server, expose it to the Internet, and access the internal network via the VPN. This way, your phone would be recognized by username/password.

Comment: Interesting idea. This could be a solution.